# SSRS 2008 Bubble Chart Conditional Formatting Overrides Mean

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 to create a bubble chart. There is a `Vendor` parameter I am using to color the bubble(s) when selected. The expression:

`=iif (Fields!Vendor.Value = Parameters!Select_Vendor.Value, "Red", "Gold")` is in the Marker Color. All this works fine.

The issue is when I add a calculated Mean series. (Most other calculated series formulas except Median are OK but not useful to me). The Mean seems to take on the properties of the Series - color, bubble label. The some of the color of the bubble and bubble label also appear on the Mean line.

Is this a bug? is there any work-around? Is there a way to add my own custom Mean line?

Comment: How does your mean should look?, Explain your expected bubble chart specially how you want to show the calculated mean series. Also a dataset sample is useful.

Comment: Is your MEAN using multiple Vendors? The issue could be that it uses the first Vendor it finds in the data. It might be helpful if you put a pic on imgur and put the link in your question.

Comment: http://jlucero.imgur.com/all/

Comment: It seems like it is not just conditional formatting - it occurs when you change the Automatic marker color to a hard-coded color - only for Mean and Median.

Comment: I clicked that link you posted - it says "jlucero's images are not publicly available"

Comment: Sorry - new to imgur - set to public